# Glass mapper and Drop Link field in Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a state field, a drop link type field, that points to a section of the reusable content area in my content tree. I'm trying to use glass mapper and edit frame to get this field to show me the list of states in the Page Editor mode.

I haven't seen any documentation related to this so looking for a way on how to get it working.

THanks

Comment: See Ruuds answer, if you still have problems then ping me a message.

Answer (score 2):

These two resources will tell you all you need:

Edit Frames in Sitecore (explains the basic, without Glass) 
http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/

Edit Frames with Glass Mapper
http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14.aspx

Comment: The URLs to the tutorials have changed for Glass Mapper but no redirects in place.  Here is the updated link to the [Edit Frames with Glass Mapper](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14.aspx).